# In Razor Pages view, why won't href and onclick attributes render?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

In a Razor Pages view (no "@page" attribute; just a cshtml file), I'm attempting to render an anchor tag. I don't want to employ the tag helper, I just want it to render like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascriptFunctionCall(1)" class="page-link"><i class="fas fa-fast-backward"></i></a>
```

The view renders with no error message, but the "href" and "onclick" attributes inside the anchor tag simply do not render. The "class" attribute does render. If I add other attributes to the tag they also render. I'm using fontawesome icons, and they render properly. But the "href" and "onclick" attributes do not render.

For the "href" attribute, if I change the value to "#", it renders. Obviously, something in the RazorPages rendering engine is saying "I will not render this" if the attribute contains javascript.

This apparently only happens in a view. I notice that I try to render the same element on a page (has the @page attribute) it renders fine.

The view itself is rendered when a user clicks a button, which makes a fetch call, which hits a server-side method that renders the view like this:

```
return Partial("_MyViewName", myModel);
```

Is there any way to render static values in the href and onclick attributes in an anchor tag in a Razor view?

Comment: normal tags should not be touched by the razor engine ***unless*** you have some `TagHelperComponent` that targets the `a` tag. Note that, it's not `TagHelper` which must be used explicitly. `asp.net core` has 2 built-in `TagHelperComponent`s targeting `head` and `body`. For other tags (such as `a`), there must be a custom one declared in your project or some referenced library. So it's hard to say. A `TagHelperComponent` can modify the rendered output for the targeted tag. In your case the `onclick` & `href` may be somehow removed.

Comment: @KingKing no, there is no custom tag helper declared in my project or in any referenced library. It is a new RazorPages project, and I'm not referencing anything that contains a custom tag helper. I have the same issue when I switch to a <button>: the "onclick" does not render. And I notice that the "href" will not render if it contains javascript, but if it simply contains "#" it renders fine. The existence of javascript is causing the attribute to fail to render. I added some detail on how I am rendering the view.

Comment: this is just too strange, as I said, if it's removed, there must be some code that removes it. And a `TagHelperComponent` is just a rare one that can do that. `Partial` or `View` should not matter in this case. Also, there may be some `javascript` code which can also modify the elements after loaded. So if possible, you can try loading your view by some browser or tool with `javascript` disabled.

Comment: btw, the browser itself may also modify the elements the way it wants, so try it on a different browser as well.

Comment: @KingKing This is only happening when I do it in a view (no page directive) and render it via call to Partial. I suppose this is some security thing. I find it very curious that I cannot find it documented anywhere.

Comment: I've just tested a simple demo in which an ajax call loads a partial view (that has the exact `a` element as in your example) and it just outputs the exact html with nothing removed. In other words, I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @KingKing in that case please show me your code; we must be doing something different. I'll expand my question to note exactly how I'm fetching the view.

Comment: it's just basic, nothing special. A partial view contains just one line (in your example). A page handler returning `Partial("_Test");` (the partial view is named `_Test.cshtml`). That's all. A button on a page, clicking on that button sends a request to the partial handler using jQuery `$.ajax`.

Comment: @KingKing I owe you a favor. As I started to expand my question I noticed and remembered that I'm passing the returned html from fetch calls through the DOMPurify library, which removes javascript by design. Problem here was between my ears. Thank you forcing me to step through it and figure it out..

Comment: yes, there is definitely some code somewhere interfering in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inadvertently removing the javascript myself because, in javascript, I was passing the value returned from the server through the DOMPurify library (to guard against a javascript injection attack). This was very stupid of me, but special thank you to @KingKing for forcing me to figure it out.